# How to add more pages to android app?

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I am a bit confused as I am new to android development. Let me put a scenario:

My app has 2 activities

1. SQL Lite DB related
2. List view

How should I use Android studio to combine both of the above? I cannot find a conclusive answer on the internet so that's why I am asking all the professionals out there.

Comment: [Introduction to Activities](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities)

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking to have both in one page? In that case I would consider using Fragments, in which multiple to could housed into one activity and can run there. Could you elaborate more on what you are trying to do?

If you want to connect a ListView to some SQL database, there are many ways you can display that, but it depends on how the database is laid out.

Comment: I just want to know how can I add multiple activities to a single Android app. The above ones are just mentioned as an example. It can be any number of activities. List view, SQL, Intent, video player etc.

Comment: @MuhammadMunzir Go to app -> right click on java folder -> new -> activity and select the type of activity you want. You can find an image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/83g2V.png

Comment: Thanks a lot... its all for now